# How to move Google Sheets (via Query function) data one column to the right and add a constant string on the left?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I want to select some data from Tab 1 and Tab 2 via the query function and have it appear one column to the right. But on the empty column to the left, I want a constant string appearing.

*Query is important because I'm using this on the Analytics Add On API.

Eg: Tab 1 has information about Mangoes. Column A has Dates, Column B has Sessions. Tab 2 has information about Oranges with Col A having dates, Col B having Sessions. On the final Tab, I want to take this data via query, and Col A needs to be "Mangoes" every time, Column B has Tab 1's Col A dates, Col C has Ta 1s Col Bs Sessions. Once the Mangoes tab data finishes, I need the "Oranges" data to appear.

It's important I do this via a query because I need to take multiple tab information and collate it in on the final Tab.

Final result example:

```
Mangoes | 01/01/2020 | 2520
Mangoes | 02/01/2020 | 3423
Oranges | 01/01/2020 | 2343
Oranges | 01/01/2020 | 5677
```

Current formula looks like:
`=QUERY({Tab1!A15:B;Tab2!A15:B},"SELECT * where Col1 is not null",1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to have it.

For me the simpliest way is to query each range adding one column with fixed value on the left.
Then stack these new built ranges and query again:

```
=QUERY(
{query({'Tab1'!A15:B},"select 'Mangoes', Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null",0);
 query({'Tab2'!A15:B},"select 'Oranges', Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null",0)},
"SELECT * where Col2 is not null",0)
```

[image]